# two ways to compute average prices

Tags: mean

I am doing some simple math computation. I have three variables: Goods, total price, and total unit (See below). All I wanted to do is to compute the average price per unit.

[image]

Method 1

I computed price per unit for each goods: total_price/total_unit. This gives me the column "price_per_unit_per_goods". Then I compute the the average price per unit by sum the 5 numbers of price_per_unit_per_goods and divide the sum by 5. So (196.0784+1000+714.2857+655.7377+2380.952)/5 = 989.4108.

Method 2

I just did sum of total price divided by sum of total unit. So (10000+20000+30000+40000+50000)/(51+20+42+61+21) = 769.2308

My question. Why is the average price per unit not the same using these two methods (989.4108 vs. 769.2308)?

Any explanations (with references) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of problems often become more intuitive when you make a more extreme sample:

Let's compute the average wealth of people in a village by considering the group of millionairs and the group of others

```
                   Wealth           N people   average person wealth
millionairs        4 000 000            2       2 000 000
others            19 960 000          998          20 000

tot               23 960 000        1 000
```

- **method 1**
  average of the group averages ... the average of 2 000 000 and 20 000 $$\frac{2\, 020\, 000}{2} = \frac{2 \, 000 \, 000 + 20 \, 000}{1+1} = 1\, 010 \, 000$$
- **method 2** average of the individuals ... the average of 2 000 000 and a lot of 20 000's.$$\begin{array}{}
   \frac{23\, 960\, 000}{1 \, 000} &=&\frac{2 \times 2 \, 000 \, 000 +
     998 \times 20 \, 000}{2+998} &&\\ &=& \frac{2 \, 000 \, 000 + 2 \,
     000 \, 000 + 20 \, 000 + 20 \, 000 + ... + 20 \, 000+ 20 \,
     000}{1+1+...+1+1} &=& 23 \, 960 \end{array}$$

---

You could see the difference as is in how often you count the 2 000 000 and 20 000.

a general formula could be:

$$ \frac{\text{total } X}{ \text{total } N} = \frac{N_1 \frac{X_1}{N_1} + N_2 \frac{X_2}{N_2} + N_3 \frac{X_3}{N_3} + ... }{N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + ...}$$

but not

$$ \frac{\text{total } X}{ \text{total } N} = \frac{1 \frac{X_1}{N_1} + 1 \frac{X_2}{N_2} + 1 \frac{X_3}{N_3} + ... }{1+1+1 + ...}$$

Answer (score 2):

The average price per unit using these two methods is not the same because the two methods are fundamentally different. Allow me to explain:

In method 1, you are not calculating the average price per unit; you are actually calculating the average price per unit goods *by type*.  Goods A, which has 51 units, is held equally to Goods B, which has far fewer units.  Because of this, the average price per unit goods is skewed more towards the price of Goods A than the price of Goods B.

In method 2, you are calculating the average price per unit correctly, (obviously).

If you would like to adjust method 1 to match method 2, you should use a [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) where the weights for Goods A,B,C,D,E are the number of units of each respective Goods.